# POO - ¿Como comparo fecha actual con la de un cumpleaños en Java?

Tags: java

Mi duda es si estoy haciendo bien la comparación acá de la fecha:

```java
public boolean esCumpleanos() {
    fechaNacimiento = Calendar.getInstance();
    this.setfechaNacimiento(fechaNacimiento);
    Calendar fechahoy = Calendar.getInstance();

    if (this.getfechaNacimiento().equals(fechahoy)) {
        return true;
    }else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Acá subo una fecha y lo compara en el ejecutable:

```java
public static void main (String [] args) {
    Scanner teclado = new Scanner (System.in);
    teclado.useDelimiter("\n");
    Persona unaper = new Persona (3255346 , "Juan " , "Perez", 12-8-21);

    if (unaper.esCumpleanos() == true) {
        System.out.println("FELIZ CUMPLEAÑOS");
    }else {
        System.out.println("no es ");
    }
```

Comment: Si estas buscando comparar la hora, creo que lo que buscas es compareTo. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-compare-two-dates-in-java

Comment: no estoy tratando de comparar la fecha para que me diga si es cumpleaños o no

Answer (score 0):

La siguiente sentencia está mal definida

> if (unaper.esCumpleanos() == true)

debido a que el if ya devuelve un valor true, entonces la forma correcta será

```
if (unaper.esCumpleanos())
```

A partir de java 8 en adelante te sugiero hacer uso del paquete [java.time](https://www.campusmvp.es/recursos/post/como-manejar-correctamente-fechas-en-java-el-paquete-java-time.aspx) para manejos de fecha y hora.
Te dejo un ejemplo adecuando a tu pregunta.

```
public class Persona {
    private int id;
    private String nombre;
    private String apellido;
    private LocalDate fechaNacimiento;
    
    private Persona(int id, String nombre, String apellido, LocalDate fechaNacimiento) {
        this.id=id;
        this.nombre=nombre;
        this.apellido=apellido;
        this.fechaNacimiento=fechaNacimiento;
    }

    public LocalDate getFechaNacimiento() {
        return fechaNacimiento;
    }
    
    
    public boolean esCumpleanos() {
        
        LocalDate fechahoy = LocalDate.now();

        if (fechaNacimiento.equals(fechahoy)) {
            return true;
        }else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    
    public static void main (String [] args) {
        Scanner teclado = new Scanner (System.in);        
        Persona unaper = new Persona (3255346 , "Juan " , "Perez", LocalDate.of(2021, Month.AUGUST, 12));

        if (unaper.esCumpleanos()) {
            System.out.println("FELIZ CUMPLEAÑOS");
        }else {
            System.out.println("no es ");
        }
    }
```